# How to get small and large picture profile on facebook passport startegy

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js

I can get facebook picture profile large and small seperately, but how to get them in the same time ?

```
var fbStrategy = configAuth.facebookAuth;
    fbStrategy.passReqToCallback = true;
    fbStrategy.profileFields = ['id', 'name','photos', 'emails'],
    // fbStrategy.profileFields = ['id', 'name','picture.type(large)', 'emails'],
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(fbStrategy,
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
```

Comment: what is the point of getting the small one too? you can just resize the large one on your own, for example.

Comment: I want to have the two pictures dynamically, and i will not upload them to the server, because user can at each time change his picture profile

Comment: you can also resize them with css, for example. no need to fetch 2 pictures, if you need the large one anyway.

Comment: Theoretically possible using field aliases, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields